# Apply (newly imported) filters to messages in:Inbox (not All Messages) (or other subsets)

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

---+ BRIEF:

Is there a convenient way in Gmail's existing interface to apply a bunch [*]  of filters to messages that are in the Inbox,  but not elsewhere?

Where  "bunch" =  too many filters for me to want to go unselect them one by one, modify their queries to apply in:Inbox,  etc.

---+ DETAIL:

I have wanted this in  several situations, but I might as well explain my particular use case today:

I just made a fairly large global edit to the  exported Gmail filters mailFilters.xml.   I changed the name of some labels,  and I  changed a whole slew of existing filters to skip the inbox, i.e. to archive immediately, in addition to the labels that they apply.

When I import these new filters,  Gmail gives me the option of applying them to all existing email (except for that in Trash or Spam). However,  I only want to  apply them to email it is in:Inbox;    I don't want to apply them to email that I've already processed, that is already archived.

(Futhermore, but  lower priority: some of the labels I apply are of the form Inbox-low-priority (actually, ",Inbox" for me),  which I use as a rather low priority inbox -  so I can get this clutter out of my main Inbox, but still find it.   what I really want is to apply this bunch of imported filters to all email that is currently in:Inbox or label:,Inbox ---   but I would be happy just to limit it to in:Inbox)

---

I can imagine playing games with labels,   e.g. labeling things that are already processed, applying the imported filters to everything, and then  the messages that have already been processed from inbox.   but I won't call this convenient, because frankly it takes a damned long time -  and I admit that I've done this in the past, and occasionally made errors, and ended up with 5000  reincarnated zombie emails in my in box. So I'm looking for a better way.

---+  background

In case anyone cares, I export my Gmail filters for purposes of version control.

I have way too many Gmail filters, partially because of history, but mostly because Gmail search folders are not first-class objects (e.g.  they do not persist in the user interface, and they do not display message counts the way search folders in Outlook or eMclient or Thunderbird do come even when applied to Gmail labels).    I am not using  the pseudo-first-class search folders of Outlook or eMclient or Thunderbird because  I can't version control them.   you can supposedly version control Thunderbird filters/search folders/virtual folders, but I cannot get that to work reliably.   and even if I did ...  using any of these would get me locked into a particular email reader, whereas Gmail labels  can be accessed across all or at least most of the email readers that can access Gmail via IMAP.

i.e. a population explosion of Gmail labels and filters somewhat makes up for Gmail lacking first-class search folders, and makes the feature cross mail reader.

but Gmail certainly does not make it easy to manipulate large numbers of labels or folders.

Hence the exporting them to XML and editing them off-line.

Work in progress:    automating operations such as applying multiple labels as a result of the same filter query ...  i.e. replicating the XML filter   so that each only applies one label, even though the predicates are identical.

I have no reason to believe that anybody else cares, except possibly commiserate about how  pitiful Gmail labels support is. But I'm providing this background because people in StackExchange often ask "what is the real problem that you are trying to solve?"  but if anybody can point me to commandline tools that do the operations that I want,  that would make me even more happy.

realistically, I'm allowed to hope that somebody may  have figured out a nice way to apply a bunch of filters to messages in inbox but nowhere else.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: See the first paragraph, Or if you wish the first section the limited by the heading BRIEF, separated from supporting detail in a separate section. A common style writing English is to use a pyramid construction, especially in journalism: the first pmaragraph Is the key point, in this case the actual question, and everything else is supporting material. In journalism it can be cut off at almost any subsequent point. This style may not be familiar to you, especially if English is not your native language, or if you have never written for a newspaper or magazine.

Comment: I'm still not clear why you need to exclude the inbox.  I assume it screws something up but since most of filtering is labeling and since it won't 'remove' labels, why would applying it blow everything up?  Regardless since you know how to export to  xml just add in:inbox to all the rules, reimport and run them, then, restore the rules minus the in:inbox  qualifier for new messages.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @BlindSpots: I think you misread my question. The “brief” summary says “apply a bunch of filters to messages that are in the Inbox but not elsewhere.” I.e. INCLUDE the Inbox, not exclude the inbox. // anticipating next question: automatically apply filters to messages in:Inbox, is a heuristic that may be wrong; when I remove from Inbox I manually fix miss-labelling. // key: multiple filters - it’s easy to do for a single filter

Comment: In:inbox means that in order for a message to meet the criteria it must be in the inbox, ie will not apply to messages that are not in the inbox

Comment: Again @BlindSpots, you miss my point: I have many filters designed to be run on incoming mail. I would like to run them all on my inbox. Gmail allows you to select multiple filters and apply them, but as far as I know it applies them to all email, not just email in your inbox, resulting in the. problems I described both in the original question and in my reply to you. While I could go and modify them one by one to have in:Inbox applied, I am looking for a way that does not require that manual editing.

Comment: I'm certainly trying but there is a bit of a challenge for me as you don't speak in Gmail :-)  I am the right resource for you so worth the effort to make things clear.

Comment: My assumptions are:

1 You want to perform a large number of 1 off labeling operations

2 You have the logic pre-defined in existing filters with the sole exception that they should be  restricted to in:inbox

3 Editing a large number of filters is easy in XML using a text tool of choice to find/replace

Comment: Can you identify anything so far in my assumptions where we diverge?

Comment: Finally we agree.  In fact, I was just about to post that the best way I have found to do this has been to export my filters to XML, edit them adding in:Inbox, import the modified filters, select them, apply them, and then delete the filter versions that had in:Inbox applied. Straightforward but IMHO not convenient.

Comment: So I'm not missing any point.  My first comment suggested this "Regardless since you know how to export to xml just add in:inbox to all the rules, reimport and run them, then, restore the rules minus the in:inbox qualifier for new messages. Am I missing something?"  Don't understand your resistance.  This is already an atypical use of rules which are intended for incoming mail,  already leverages some of your existing behavior (exporting XML for versioning) with a twist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139621/discussion-between-blind-spots-and-krazy-glew).

Comment: If you are interested in the approach I detailed in the chat (tagging and trash'ing) I will flesh it out properly as an answer, as the chat was a bit of a brain dump.

Comment: Sure, convert it to an answer and I’ll approve it and give you credit;  Although I knew of this approach at the time I posted, I did not make it explicit in my background details to the original question. Which the original commenter thought was already too long.//I was actually hoping that there was a webpage centred way to do this, but again I did not make that sufficiently clear in my original question.